# Cloning Object properties/values Directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to clone object properties value into a null variable or empty object.
I don't know whether we can achieve it or not therefore I am having this doubt I searched but didn't get a solution

event has keys --> **firstName, lastName and age**

I have tried to set state directly using set state method

`this.setState({currentEvent:event});`

Here is the complete code:

```
   this.state = {
      dialogEvent:false,
      currentEvent:{},
    }

  }

  handleClickButton = event => {
   // event is the single event that needs to be updated in parent event 
     after updating age.

  console.log(event);

  axios.get(configs.Data.getNewAge)
  .then(res=>{
       console.log(res); // res.data.newObj has time date and time epoch

       Object.keys(event).forEach(function(index){
            console.log(index);
       }); // checking the keys for event by logging

     this.setState({currentEvent:event});

       this.setState({eventDialog:true}); // this is the dialog
  }).catch((e)=>console.log("Error :"+e));


  };
```

**Actual Results:** currentEvent is undefined if fetched in dialog

**Expected Results:** it should have cloned all properties and values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
const event = {firstName:"fn",lastName:"ln",age:99}
let currentEvent = {...event}
console.log(currentEvent)
```

Comment: but there was another part of this question if we have to change the age where server returns new age how to update that?

Answer (score 1):

Try cloning the `event` object.

```
  handleClickButton = event => {
  const currentEvent = Object.assign({}, event);

  axios.get(configs.Data.getNewAge)
  .then(res => {
     this.setState({currentEvent});

  }).catch((e)=>console.log("Error :"+e));

  };
```